# Cannot perform operations using rpy2 in Python: "TypeError: argument 1 must be a str, not int"

Tags: python, r, typeerror, rpy2

So I'm trying to get to grips with using the rpy2 module (I am familiar with R but new to Python).  Following [this](https://github.com/thehackerwithin/Python2010/wiki/PyBCSession08) tutorial, I first load the library and assign it to the variable 'r' using:

```
import rpy2
import rpy2.robjects as robjects
r = robjects.r
```

then I try to perform a simple operation to confirm everything is working:

```
print(r[2+2])
```

but I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\rpy2\robjects\__init__.py", line 248, in _
_getitem__
    res = _globalenv.get(item)
TypeError: argument 1 must be str, not int
```

I'm sure it's just something stupid I'm doing wrong, but any advice would be much appreciated.  I'm using python3.4.2 (64bit), rpy2-2.5.6 (64bit) on a Windows 7 machine (64bit).

Comment: What do you expect from `print(r[2+2])`?

Comment: The official documentation has a short introduction. You may want to check it out: http://rpy.sourceforge.net/rpy2/doc-2.5/html/introduction.html

Comment: Thanks @lgautier, I already have and I still get the same error. When following these instructions I type `utils = rpackages.importr("utils")`, I get `NameError: name "rpackages" is not defined`.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `print(r(2+2))` instead of `print(r[2+2])`.

When you use `r[2+2]` you are trying to recover an element corresponding to the index `4` (the result of `2+2`) of the `r` iterable. And your `r` object doesn't seem to respond to this kind of message.

Comment: Thank you, sorry I should have said that I want the console to print "4".  When I do as you suggest, I get:                                                         `>>> print(r(2+2))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\rpy2\robjects\__init__.py", line 268, in _
_call__
    p = rinterface.parse(string)
ValueError: The object to parse must be a unicode string`

Answer (score 0):

Ok I think I have figured it out.  For R to evaluate the function inside the parenthesis, the function must be in quotes e.g.

```
r("2+2")
```

This is what was confusing me because this looks like I'm providing a string.
Oddly I don't print the result (4) by using:

```
print(r("2+2"))
```

as this prints:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#31>", line 1, in <module>
    print(r("2+2"))
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\rpy2\robjects\robject.py", line 49, in __str__
    s = str.join(os.linesep, s)
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, bytes found
```

Instead I just print the result using:

```
answer = r("2+2")
answer[0]
```

(Because R is vector based, the initial value of the vector is the answer so you have to index it at the first position, otherwise you get:

```
answer = r("2+2")
answer
<FloatVector - Python:0x0000000005836EC8 / R:0x00000000047A51A0>

[4.000000]
```

Thanks for you help

Hefin